# Factorization of Normal Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, orthonormal, isometry

Here is a theorem on [Treil's textbook](https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/sergei-treil-homepage/linear-algebra-done-wrong):

> Theorem $2.4.$ Any normal operator $N$ in a complex vector space has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. In other words, $N=UDU^*$, where $U$ is a unitary matrix, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

My question is:

Must $D$ have the eigenvalues of $N$ on its main diagonals?

I assume yes, but do not quite understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and (for this part of the statement) the fact that $N$ is normal is irrelevant.  We have
$$NU=UD\ ,$$
and extracting the $k$th column on both sides gives
$$N{\bf u}_k=\lambda_k{\bf u}_k\ .$$

Comment: How do you know $u_k$ is an eigenvector?

Comment: $U$ is invertible so ${\bf u}_k$ can't be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the diagonal entries of $D$ are precisely the eigenvalues of $N$.  Note that for $\lambda\in\mathbb C$, the operator
$$UDU^*-\lambda=U(D-\lambda)U^*$$
is invertible if and only if $D-\lambda$ is invertible, and this happens if and only if $\lambda$ is not on the diagonal of $D$.